# Loop through a DB Table return results in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, loops, while-loop

Hi A DB with a table called Users:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| user_id | Affiliate        | total |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
|       1 | Aff1            |    10 |
|       2 | Aff1           |     10 |
|       3 | Aff2           |     5 |
|       4 | Aff2           |     5 |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
```

What i want to do is loop through the records so i can echo out the following results :

```
Aff1 20
Aff2 10
```

As you can see it adds there values in the DB.

I have tried the query:

```
$data = DB::table('users')
    ->sum('total');

return view('home', compact('data'));
```

Im not sure what to do now or how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is group by the Affiliate, there is a function in laravel to use the group by function of sql.

Try this:
`$data = DB::table('users')->groupBy('Affiliate')->sum('total')->get();`

Comment: in blade u can do it like this:
    @foreach($data as $user)
{{$user->affiliate}} {{$user->total}}
@endforeach